# IconItemRenderer: How to display decorator only for some List items?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, itemrenderer, flex-mobile, flex4.10

With Flex 4.10 and a spark List using [IconItemRenderer](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html) -

is it please possible to display decorator images only for some List items?

I have a List representing a weekly Top-rating of players and wonder how to display the medal for winners only:

[image]

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="MEDAL"
        source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/160/medal-gold.png')"
        source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/240/medal-gold.png')"
        source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/320/medal-gold.png')"
        source480dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/480/medal-gold.png')" />

    <s:ArrayCollection id="_ac" />
</fx:Declarations>


<s:List id="_list"
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" 
        dataProvider="{_ac}" 
        change="handleChange(event)">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer 
                iconField="avatar" 
                messageField="city" 
                decorator="{outerDocument.MEDAL}"
                iconFunction="{outerDocument.iconFunc}" 
                labelFunction="{outerDocument.labelFunc}" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to set the decorator to null in your data change function.

Longer answer:

```
<s:IconItemRenderer 
                iconField="avatar" 
                messageField="city" 
                decorator="{outerDocument.MEDAL}"
                iconFunction="{outerDocument.iconFunc}" 
                labelFunction="{outerDocument.labelFunc}"                   
                dataChange="onDataChange(event)" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            public var statManager :StatManager = StatManager.instance;     

            protected function onDataChange(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if(SomeConditionThatDeterminesThatDecoratorShouldBeDisplayed){
                    this.decorator = outerDocument.MEDAL;
                } else {
                    this.decorator = null;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

I use this same approach in my mobile game.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've tried same code in `set data` method and it works too, wonder where is a better place for this code?

Comment: I always prefer to use a handler on the dataChange event.  But, I have no argument that it is better.  Using dataChange or set data doesn't really natter. If you want to get "Component LifeCycle specific" then the set data should call invalidateDisplayList() and the UI change should be done in the updateDisplayList function.  Unless you're focusing on extendable /reusable components that is probably overkill.